# Only remove duplicates records from csv file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've tried googling different things, but I can't seem to find an answer.

## Csv Contents

```
"ColumnOne","ColumnTwo","ColumnThree"
"C1V1","C2V1","C3V1"
"C1V2","C2V2","C3V2"
"C1V2","C2V2","C3V2"
"C1V3","C2V3","C3V3"
```

## Code

```
$input = 'C:\Temp\test.csv'
$inputCsv = Import-Csv $input | Select-Object -Unique

$inputCsv | Export-Csv "$input-temp.csv" -NoTypeInformation
#Move-Item "$input-temp.csv" $input -Force
```

## Output

```
"ColumnOne","ColumnTwo","ColumnThree"
"C1V2","C2V2","C3V2"
```

## Expected output

```
"ColumnOne","ColumnTwo","ColumnThree"
"C1V1","C2V1","C3V1"
"C1V2","C2V2","C3V2"
"C1V3","C2V3","C3V3"
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `Select-Object -Unique` -> `Select-Object * -Unique`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the column name with either Select-Object or Sort-Object to get unique results. Try the below code if you want to sort as well. If you don't want then use Select-Object.

```
$input = 'C:\Temp\test.csv'
$inputCsv = Import-Csv $input | Sort-Object * -Unique

$inputCsv | Export-Csv "$input-temp.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

You can also refer the blog [HERE](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/01/use-powershell-to-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-csv-file/).

Comment: Oh wow thanks, I thought it would have automatically selected all the columns. that one little wildcard character was the change needed.